# What is causing these SVG/CSS animations to break in certain browsers?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, webkit

**Hey there!**

I'm in the middle of re-designing my [site](http://nicholasdumais.com/test/) and
I have a bunch of svg/css animations that break outside of chrome and I can't figure out why.

It seems to have something to do with handling multiple nested animations and transform-origins (they're not handling them).

I checked compatibility - good, if browsers handle origins differently - nope.

I don't have enough rep to post the appropriate links(too many) and code (too long) :\ but if you could inspect the site I'd be extremely grateful.

Thank you in advance for any effort put into this.

**EDIT:** fixed test case http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KJlkb

**ANSWER**: Firefox does not support percentages for objects (I'm not certain, but it seems to only affect path and g elements).

**SOLUTION:** Animate using pixels instead of percentages.  Use transform origin as if it were relevant to the SVGs viewBox dimensions instead of the objects dimensions.

Thanks to [Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) for setting me on the right path.  His link is in the comments.

Comment: please give an example of which specific animation breaks

Comment: Oh man, All of them to be honest.  If you check it out in chrome you'll see the difference.  For example the clock should rotate.. well, like a clock, but it's flying around everywhere.

Comment: You really need to break this down into specific testcases.

Comment: Here's an example I'm adding to the edit as well http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KJlkb

Comment: That one's: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=891074

Comment: Thanks Robert, your link gave a few options to explore and I found one that seems to work very well.  Solution in the edit.

Comment: Nick, you should add your answer as an answer and then accept it. Otherwise people will keep clicking through to add an answer if it's not marked as answered.

Comment: Thanks Mike, Not enough rep :\ I have to wait about 3 more hours.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:** Firefox does not support percentages for objects (I'm not certain, but it seems to only affect path and g elements).

**SOLUTION:** Animate using pixels instead of percentages. Use transform origin as if it were relevant to the SVGs viewBox dimensions instead of the objects dimensions.

Fixed test case http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KJlkb now works in FF.

Thanks to [Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) for setting me on the right path. His link is in the comments.